# How to set moment to empty depending on select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, antd

I want to set the start date and end date to undefined when select item change, I have used useEffect to handle this but on the UI the date don't set to empty.
this my code

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<moment.Moment>();
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState<moment.Moment>();

  const onChange = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      setEndDate(value);

    },
    [setEndDate, setIsMoreThenBalance]
  );

  const onChangeStartDate = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      setStartDate(value);
    },
    [setStartDate]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedLeaveId) {
      setStartDate(undefined);
      setEndDate(undefined);

    }
  }, [selectedLeaveId]);

return(

    <StyleDatePicker
      onChange={(date) => {
        onChangeStartDate(date);
      }}
      disabledDate={disableStartDate}
      value={startDate}
      format="DD/MM/YYYY"
      autoFocus
    />

    <StyleDatePicker
      onChange={(date) => {
         onChange(date);
      }}
      value={endDate}
      disabled={!startDate}
      disabledDate={disableEndDate}
      $isThereError={isMoreThenBalance}
      format="DD/MM/YYYY"
     />
 )
```

the date picker should clear the startDate and endDate every time the select another leave

[image]

Comment: Could you share a simple sample of your code in codesandbox?

Comment: What is `selectedLeaveId` can't see it anywhere in your code except as a dependency or condition? Anyways you should not implicitly set the states as a moment object, but just set it as a moment object when you dont want to set it as undefined. Moment will always return the current date when passing undefined.

Answer (score 1):

i have fixed  the issue , just add  `form.resetFileds()`  here

````
useEffect(() => {
   if (selectedLeaveId) {
     setStartDate(undefined);
     setEndDate(undefined);
     form.resetFileds();

   }
 }, [selectedLeaveId]); ```

and it's work fine . thank you
````